# highcharts gantt how to make navigator show milestones only?

Tags: highcharts

I have a gantt chart with milestones and pills, at the end I have the navigator which show all tasks (pills and milestones alike), we would like to know if there's a way to limit the navigator to show only milestones in the bar? in the image below, you can see the actual bar, we did read the docs but could not find anything like that or at least we could not find it... thank you for your help.
[image]

--------------- IMAGES FOR @SEBASTIAN ---------------

Am I missing something? Thank you for your help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case when you set the [navigator.series](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/navigator.series) options like `pointPlacement` and `pointPadding` with `pointWidth` inside [series.gantt](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/series.gantt.pointWidth) you will show milestones only at the navigator.

```
  navigator: {
    enabled: true,
    series: {
      type: 'gantt',
      pointPlacement: 0.5,
      pointPadding: 0.5,
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 4,
      reversed: true,
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    data: [{
      name: 'Create prototype',
      id: 'prototype',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 18),
      end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21)
    }, {
      name: 'Prototype done',
      dependency: 'prototype',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 12),
      milestone: true,
      pointWidth: 10,
    }, {
      name: 'Develop',
      id: 'develop',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20),
      end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25)
    }, {
      name: 'Development done',
      dependency: 'develop',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25, 12),
      milestone: true,
      pointWidth: 10,
    }, {
      name: 'Test prototype',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 27),
      end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 29)
    }, {
      name: 'Run acceptance tests',
      start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 23),
      end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 26)
    }]
  }]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a94xkb0c/

Comment: thank you for your reply... I see yours working (the demo) but mine is not producing the expected results, what I get is just something blank, nothing inside (I could not post an image here) will post some images on my original post (as this does not allow to include anything but text) Thank you for your help!

Comment: THANK YOU
By modifying  pointPlacement  and pointPadding to 1 resolved the problem...